# Parametric curve resembling a bean.

Tags: geometry, parametric, plane-curves, parametrization

I am looking for a parametric closed curve that roughly resembles a bean.

[image]

I am looking for something with an explicit parametrization of the form $C(t) = (X(t), Y(t))$

I tried searching online but "parametric bean" is not yielding much of use.

Comment: [Cardiods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid) can look a bit like Lima beans

Comment: while this surely an odd question, one of the related questions from the sidebare might be useful to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202315/partitioning-the-interior-of-bean-curve?rq=1

Comment: Use **splines** : it is the most flexible tool for drawing curves of any shape.

Comment: @JeanMarie Splines are annoying in that you must manually place the control points for you to get anything. An explicit parametrization without the need for control points like the suggested answer is preferable.

Comment: I agree. See a different approach I just posted.

Comment: This is quite frankly one of the best questions on this site. I am astounded by the sheer - *elegance* - of the bean drawing.

Comment: Like a cashew nut? .

Comment: About "the absolute" bean curve, see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BeanCurve.html). Remark : as often in Wolfram, the focus is on particular things, generally interesting, but lacking a greater scope).

Comment: Sorry, I only have a piecewise one, made from circular arcs. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gist/PM2Ring/28f67c4b26e172e3108ff7a44be71e3c/raw/6af54c77991a8646a26f803ee1e846c62a150adc/Borromean_anim.svg

Comment: Good question +1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A bit of experimentation got me to this:

[image]

It has the formula $$(\cos(t)-\frac{0.6}{1+9t^2},\sin(t))$$

Taken over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.

It has the disadvantage of not being periodic, but I don't know if that's a requirement, and it should be a relatively easy fix. It's also not easy to work with analytically, but I don't know what you're planning to do with it, so I don't know if that's important.

If you want it more curved you can go with:
$$(\cos(t)-\frac{1}{1+4t^2},\sin(t))$$

[image]

Comment: For future convenience, [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pb45pc3oge)'s the curve in Desmos with adjustable variables.

Comment: +1 for this nice answer

Answer (score 15):

HINT:

The domain inside is equivalent to the inside of a disk  ( [Riemann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem))-- so try using a conformal map.   Take a disk centered at the origin, dilate on the vertical and shift to the right. Now apply the complex map $z \mapsto z^2$, (even $z\mapsto z^n$). Because the square map doubles the argument the tall straight bean will wrap around the origin. Example:

$$t \mapsto (x^2-y^2, 2 x y)$$
where $(x,y)= (2 + \cos t , 3 \sin t)$ gets us a  [cashew](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/61df2pibno) nut.

[image]

$\bf{Added:}$ Should we want a filliform shape, like a snake, consider its spine ( a curve ), write as is the image of  $P(t)$ over a segment ( $P$ analytic), then extend $P$ around the segment and consider the image of a flat ellipse approximating the segment).

$\bf{Added:}$ We can also do surfaces in $3D$, by deforming some ellipsoids. Here is an example of a [surface](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ContourPlot3D%5Bx%5E2%20%2B%2024%20x%5E4%20%2B%209%20y%5E2%20%2B%2048%20x%5E2%20y%5E2%20%2B%2024%20y%5E4%20-%2030%20x%5E2%20z%20-%2030%20y%5E2%20z%20%2B%20%20%20%209%20z%5E2%20%2B%2048%20x%5E2%20z%5E2%20%2B%2048%20y%5E2%20z%5E2%20-%2030%20z%5E3%20%2B%2024%20z%5E4%20%3D%3D%200%2C%20%7Bx%2C%20-.3%2C%20.3%7D%2C%20%7By%2C%20-.3%2C%20.3%7D%2C%20%7Bz%2C%20.4%2C%201%7D%5D), image of an ellipsoid under inversion. (Looks like a cashew nut, in 3D).

Comment: Excellent idea.

Comment: @Jean Marie: Thank you for the kind words!  I wonder if we can take a 3D shape and try to write a certain mapping of the sphere ( preferably polynomial) that resembles the image. It's not easy since we need to manipulate so many parameters and we do not understand well the effect on the image.  Neural networks maybe?

Comment: If I understand it correctly this solution is both periodic and analytic, two features the currently accepted solution is lacking. So if these are required this is the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simple approach using connected circular arcs with (set apart parameter $t$ which is implicit), uses two parameters $a,b$ (which are the circles radii).  For an interactive experience, move the sliders $a,b$ in this Geogebra animation [here](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/ajnngvbf) ; click on the "algebra" icon on the left if you want to see details.

[image]

The circular arcs are $P'P$ centered in $O$,  $PR$ centered in $Q$, $RR'$ centered again in $O$, $R'P'$ centered in $Q'$.

Please note that any connecting point of two circular arcs is aligned with the centers of these arcs, warranting "smoothness" (differentiability) at the connecting point.

Comment: About curves made of connected circular arcs see the very nice article [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00004-014-0189-5#:~:text=an%20egg%2Dshape%20(or%206,sharing%20a%20common%20tangent%20(Fig.)) about egg drawing.

Answer (score 10):

This interesting question about curve synthesis made me de-lurk. Here's my modest attempt:

$$\begin{align*}x&=3+2\sin t+\cos 2t\\y&=4\cos t-\sin 2t\end{align*}\quad t\in[0,2\pi]$$
[image: J.M.'s bean curve]

I don't want to say too much about where it came from, except that it was part of a series of experiments on fudging around with hypotrochoids.

Comment: Nice! Could be equivalently written as $3ie^\vartheta + ie^{-\vartheta} + e^{2\vartheta}$, with $x$ and $y$ as real and imaginary parts. This is of course a (very short) Fourier series. And _any_ shape could be represented arbitrarily close as a Fourier series.

Comment: Quite economical!   Can you really describe it as the trace of a movement of a point?